# Working example with sp.profiles.clientPeoplePickerSearchUser from PnP @pnp/sp

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, 2016, typescript, pnp-js-core

I'm trying to take advantage of the people picker search helper in the PnP-JS-Core, but I get a JSON error in SP2013, 2016 and SharePoint Online. The error is the same everywhere. If I try to get data from the same endpoint without PnP using fetch it works fine. Does anyone know how to do the same using PnP?

**app.ts**

```
import { sp } from '@pnp/sp';
import { setupPnp } from './utils/odata';
import * as toastr from "toastr";
import './app';

setupPnp();

sp.profiles.clientPeoplePickerSearchUser({
  AllowEmailAddresses: true,
  AllowMultipleEntities: false,
  AllUrlZones: false,
  MaximumEntitySuggestions: 50,
  PrincipalSource: 15,
  PrincipalType: 15,
  QueryString: 'Denis'

}).then(function (entries) {
  console.log(entries);
})
```

**odata.ts**

```
import { sp } from '@pnp/sp';

// User 'application/json;odata=verbose' for compatibility with SP2013
export const ODataMode = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
// export const ODataMode = 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata';

export const setupPnp = () => {
  sp.setup({
    sp: {
      headers: {
        Accept: ODataMode,
        'Content-Type': `application/json; odata=verbose`,
        'X-RequestDigest': document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value
      }
    }
  });
};
```

**Error**

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at
>   position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at q.postCore.then (sp.js:7282)

[image]

**Working example with fetch, without using PnP**

Example below returns values with no problems:

```
let searchString = 'zergoos';
let endpointUrl = `${_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl}/_api/SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.clientPeoplePickerSearchUser`.replace(/\/\//g, '/');

fetch(endpointUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Accept': `application/json; odata=verbose`,
        'Content-Type': `application/json; odata=verbose`,
        'X-RequestDigest': document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        queryParams: {
            __metadata: {
                type: 'SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters'
            },
            AllowEmailAddresses: true,
            AllowMultipleEntities: false,
            AllUrlZones: false,
            MaximumEntitySuggestions: 50,
            PrincipalSource: 15,
            PrincipalType: 15,
            QueryString: searchString
        }
    })
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: in you `odata.ts`, can you use `export const setupPnp = () => {
  sp.setup({
    sp: {
      headers: {
        Accept: ODataMode,
      }
    }
  });
};` and check ? Have removed the content type and request digest headers. These, i believe are not needed, the framework would handle them.

Comment: Yes, added these out of desperation. With or without them it's the same error.

Comment: ok, looks like a bug, can you check with `export const setupPnp = () => {
  sp.setup({
    sp: {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
       }
    }
  });
};` ? It works in sharepoint online

Comment: I've just tried it. Exact same error. I'm going to try to upgrade the pnp packages. Let's see if it helps.

Comment: I've upgraded @pnp/common, @pnp/odata and @pnp/sp npm packages. And now it's working fine. I wish did it earlier. Thank you for you suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug with @pnp/sp while using the `verbose` mode.

However, while using the `nometadata` or `minimalmetadata` mode, its works fine.

Have created a minimal noscript SPFx webpart. Using `@pnp/sp` version `1.0.4`.

Minimal code:

```
import { sp } from '@pnp/sp';

export default class testWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<ItestWebPartProps> {

  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void, reject: (error?: any) => void): void => {
      sp.setup({
        sp: {
          headers: {
            //"Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata"
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=minimalmetadata"
          }
        }
      });
      resolve();
    });
  }

  public render(): void {
    this.testClientPicker();
  }

  private testClientPicker(): void {
    sp.profiles.clientPeoplePickerSearchUser({
      AllowEmailAddresses: true,
      AllowMultipleEntities: false,
      AllUrlZones: false,
      MaximumEntitySuggestions: 50,
      PrincipalSource: 15,
      PrincipalType: 15,
      QueryString: 'Denis'

    }).then(function (entries) {
      console.log(entries);
    })
  }

  //standard code for property pane

}
```

Comment: Cheers, happy to help :) , feel free to open an issue [here](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues), will try to fix it or somebody from the community can pick it up

Comment: created an issue: https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/78

Comment: Looks like the issue has been fixed. Do update to the `1.0.5` release which will happen around next Friday.